# RegEx to replace the first and last character of string for a particular match

Tags: c#, .net, regex, replace

Something like this.

The sentence is

```
string ttt = "This is ?chef? and ?teacher? time";
```

This sentence should change to

```
ttt = "This is 'chef' and 'teacher' time";
```

I was looking at some online samples
  `Regex.Replace(ttt, @"\?([^\$]*)\?", "REPLACE");` but I am not able to figure out what should I write in place of **REPLACE** . It should be per word basis.

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your question but aren't you just asking for ttt = ttt.Replace("?","'"); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would reference the capture group inside the replacement call. It's called a back-reference.

```
String ttt = "This is ?chef? and ?teacher? time";
String result = Regex.Replace(ttt, @"\?([^?]*)\?", "'$1'");
Console.WriteLine(result); //=> "This is 'chef' and 'teacher' time"
```

[**Back-references**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html) recall what was matched by a [**capture group**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html) `( ... )`. A backreference is specified as (`$`); followed by a digit **indicating the number of the group** to be recalled.

**Note:** I used `[^?]` for the negation instead of matching everything except a literal `$` here.

---

But if you're just wanting to replace `?`, a simple replacement would suffice:

```
String result = ttt.Replace("?", "'");
```

Comment: Aweosme. The $1 and negation was perfect !!